# Error CS0161: Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, methods

I have this error. Can anyone tell me why?
In TA.cs

```
public class TA
{
    public TA()
    {
    }

    public static DataTable MergeTA()
    {

        DataTable myDT = new DataTable();
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("AcadYear", typeof(string));
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("NofGrp", typeof(System.Int16));
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("LecHr", typeof(int));
        ...
        ...
        ...

        DataRow myDR = myDT.NewRow();
        myDataRow["AcadYear"] = "2009";
        myDataRow["NoofGrp"] = "2";
        myDataRow["LecHr"] = "1";
        ...
        ...
        ...

        myDT.Rows.Add(myDR);
        ***return myDT;*** 

    }

}
```

In Display.aspx.cs

```
...
...
...
string strConMethod = TA.MergeTA();
        SqlConnection sqlConMethod = new SqlConnection(strConMethod);
        DataTable haha = new DataTable();
        haha = TA.MergeTA();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a DataTable from your MergeTA method.  Add this to the bottom:

```
return(myDT);
```

Comment: D'oh - beat me by one second!  I knew I shouldn't have spent time proof reading.

Comment: TLiebe, for once in ten tries I finally got one in first!  Still you currently have more votes, probably due to my "weieeerrrd" parens.  :-)

Robert, yeah, I'm weird like that.  Return just feels like something that needs an argument.  I have no idea how I picked up this habit, but back in the 20th century I must have used a C compiler that wanted it.

Comment: thanks for the comment. but by doing this, i have a new error.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'

Comment: Yeah, I've had other almost identical answers beat mine before too.  At least I can help you out with a +1.

Comment: TLiebe, thanks, and a +1 back for your graciousness and for answering the follow-up.  Wish I could +2.

Comment: Ah, I can actually do that extra +1 with a comment.  There you go.

Answer (score 7):

You need to return the DataTable at the end of your function:

```
return myDT;
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. but by doing this, i have a new error.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'string'

Comment: The first line of your code in Display.aspx.cs is causing the problem.  MergeTA() returns a DataTable and you're trying to assign it to a string variable.  MergeTA() is NOT returning a connection string - you need to get the connection string from somewhere else (your app.config or web.config file, manually create it or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

You appear not to be returning `myDT` at the end of `MergeTA().`

That method is of type `DataTable`, so all code paths through it must return a `DataTable`.